# Navigation Bar remains hidden after trying to programmatically show it in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a parent view with a Navigation View and Tab View inside it. Depending on which view the user taps, the nav bar shows/hides on swipe (this works) however, if the user decides to scroll and the nar bar disappeared, it won't show again on the other pages until the user scroll up again on the pages where hidesOnSwipe is enabled. I've literally tried everything to try to force the nav bar to be visible but unfortunately, it remains hidden in other views.

[image: Gif Example]

Parent View

```
  NavigationStack {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            TabView(selection: $selectedItem.onUpdate {
                setNewValue(value: selectedItem)
            }) {
               Some views here .... 
                
                
            }
            
            
            .onChange(of: selectedItem, perform: { currentPage in
                if currentPage == 1 {         
                    pageState.hideNavigationBar = false <---- make sure it's visible 
                 on the main page (remains hidden :/)
                    pageState.hideOnSwipe = false
                   
                }
                else if currentPage == 2 {          
                    pageState.hideOnSwipe = true
                }
               
            })
            
            
            
            
        }
        .setNavigationBarHidden(pageState.hideNavigationBar)
        .navigationBarsHideOnSwipe(pageState.hideOnSwipe)
        .navigationBarTitle(pageState.navBarTitle, displayMode: .inline)
    }
    .onAppear {
        pageState.hideNavigationBar = false
        pageState.hideOnSwipe = false
    }
```

Comment: Normally the tab view would be the root view and each tab would have its own navigation stack within it. For tabs which shouldn’t show a navigation bar, you simply wouldn’t include it in that tab.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth what if you have notifications? you'd need a navigation stack on the root parent to direct you inside the app, no?